# POST Multiple PHP Variables Through Ajax to PHP Handler

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables

Whats the best way to pass multiple php variables (or database table fields) through Ajax to my handler from a `<span>` element that's being used as an icon? Thanks in advance for any help!

TABLE

```
art_id  art_title  art_company    art_featured
1       lorem 1    lorem ipsum 1  1
2       lorem 2    lorem ipsum 2  0
```

HTML/PHP

```
<section class="row">
    <?php
    $sql_categories = "SELECT art_title, art_company, art_id, art_featured FROM app_articles"; 

        if($result = query($sql_categories)){
            $list = array();

            while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                array_push($list, $data);
            }

            foreach($list as $i => $row){ 
            ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="column two"><p><?php echo $row['art_title']; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="column two"><p><?php echo $row['art_company']; ?></p></div>
                    <div class="column one"><span id="<?php echo $row['art_id']; ?>" class="icon-small star"></span></div>
                </div>
            <?php
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "FAIL";
        }
    ?>
    </section>
```

jQuery

```
        $(".star").click(function(){

        var art_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {art_id:art_id},
        url: "ajax-feature.php",
        success: function(data){
            if(data != false) {

            } 
            else {

            }  
        }
        });

    });
```

mySQL / PHP

```
    if(isset($_POST['art_id'])) {



    $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 1 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];

    if(query($sql_articles)) {
        echo "YES";
    }
    else {
        echo "NO";
    }
}
else {
    echo "FAIL";
}
```

What I'm looking to do is change the value of the field `art_featured` from 0 to 1 like say if `art_featured` is 0 then I want to update the database field to 1 and vise versa. I'm sending the `article_id` via post with jquery ajax but I don't know how to send the `article_feature` field. Because what ill end up doing is something like this i guess

```
        if($_POST['art_featured']==0) {
        $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 1 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];

    }
    else {
        $sql_articles = "UPDATE `app_articles` SET `art_featured` = 0 WHERE `art_id` =".$_POST['art_id'];
    }
```

Comment: Could you paste some code so i know what you are talking about

Comment: Sure one minute thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    ('span').click(function(){

    jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',
    data:'id=8391283&length=8943&north='+variable+'&typ=normal,

    url:'yourUrl',
    success:function(data,textStatus){alert('success')},
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
    });
```

});

this is a possible way to make an ajax request with multple params

Comment: is there a way to do something like data: id=<?php echo $row['id']?>  ?

Comment: i think so, you could replace +variable+ with <?php echo $row['id']?>

Comment: data:'id=8391283&length=8943&north='<?php echo $row['id']?>'&typ=normal,    then the parameter "north" = your row